# How to get the modified environmental variables using c programme in Mac using bash terminal

Tags: c, linux, macos, bash, unix

I want to get the modified environment variables using C a program on a Mac using a bash terminal. How do I do this?

If I use `getenv`, I will get only the default system defined environment variables - but I am not getting the modified one. Why? And how would I correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by modified ? Modified by whom/what ?

Comment: please followup the bottom post, there i have mentioned the problem..help me if u know answer

Comment: The `getenv()` function is the way to do it -- you must not be doing what you think you're doing to set the environment variable, or you're running your program in such a way as to override the environment with one from somewhere else.

Comment: @LLL, please edit your post showing the steps you are doing. See dekpos after-Edit post to see what's useful to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        setenv("PATH","/mypath",1);
        printf("%s\n",getenv("PATH"));
        return(0);
}
```

The above program outputs:

```
/mypath
```

If however you execute env in bash after your C program, you will get the PATH value which is set by default for bash.

```
$ env
...
PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/user/bin
...
```

This is because the environment variables are modified only for that particular process which is running the C program, & not for the process running bash.

**Edit:**

Writing env.c as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        printf("%s\n",getenv("PATH"));
        return(0);
}
```

followed by:

```
$ gcc env.c
$ export PATH=/bin
$ ./a.out
```

gives:

```
/bin
```

I don't see why it should be any different. (Did you do all the steps that I have done above?)

Comment: i have already modified "PATH" in my bash terminal.
Now, i want to display the modified "PATH" using c-program.how to do it

Comment: Could you properly explain the purpose of this exercise before I answer your question?

Comment: Just wanted to know that if i have modified any environment variable using bash terminal,
can i get the modified value of the environmental variable using C program? Is it possible?

Comment: Which command did you use to modify the environment variable?

Comment: Used the below specified command

export PATH=some_value     --     in bash terminal

then i used 

var_name = getenv ("PATH")    --    in  C  Program

Output:
Default value of PATH is displayed and not the modified value

Comment: @Crypto: can i create an environment variable in Bash terminal and access it using c-program?

Comment: Yes, you can simply type export NEW_VAR=NEW_VALUE, then access it in the program.

Comment: it will produce the output as 'nil' in the program

Answer (score 0):

By using `putenv(), setenv() and unsetenv()` we only affect the environment variables of current process and child process that we invoke. we can not affect the environment of parent process, which is often a shell.
By using `extern char** environ;` we can not access the modified environment variables,But the
program which is used to add or modified the environment variables can access these using `getenv()` function.
For example....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>    
main()
{

    if(putenv("COLOR=BROWN")==0)
        printf("Successful\n");
    else
        printf("Unsuccessful\n");

//If we put an environment variable it will only VISIBLE THE PROGRAMME BY WHICH IT HAS BEEN set

    char *result;
    result = getenv("COLOR");//char* getenv(const char*)
    if(result!=NULL)//if environment variable does not exist result will be NULL
        puts(result);
    else
        printf("failed to get environment variable\n");

//Modify this environment variable

    if(putenv("COLOR=RED")==0)
        printf("changing Successful\n");
    else
        printf("Unsuccessful\n");

    result = getenv("COLOR");
    if(result!=NULL)
        puts(result);
    else
        printf("failed to get environment variable\n");

//Verify with existing env variables

    if(putenv("PWD=NONE")==0)
        printf("changing Successful\n");
    else
        printf("Unsuccessful\n");

    result = getenv("PWD");
    if(result!=NULL)
        puts(result);
    else
        printf("failed to get environment variable\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int *a, char *b[], char *c[])
{
    int ctr;

    for (ctr = 0; c[ctr]; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", c[ctr]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```